# How to convert legacy "C:\Documents and Settings" paths to "C:\Users"

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I have some legacy data that was created on Windows XP. It contains absolute file names to files in users' My Documents directories. On Windows 7, these absolute references are no longer point to the correct place. For example what was "C:\Documents and Settings\Gareth\My Documents\readme.txt" should now be "C:\Users\Gareth\Documents\readme.txt".

Many Win32 functions are happy to take the file names under "C:\Documents and Settings" and to behind the scenes convert them to the new file names, however there are functions we use that don't do this. Is there a Windows API that I can use to convert these file names to the new locations?

Obviously, I could do string search and replace, but that wouldn't be guaranteed to work under all circumstances. Because there are Windows functions that seem to do the substitution it feels like there ought to be a published function I can call to do the same thing.

Just to clarify my question: I'm looking for a function that does this:

Input: "C:\Documents and Settings\Gareth\My Documents\readme.txt"
Output: "C:\Users\Gareth\Documents\readme.txt"

or

Input: "C:\Documents and Settings\Gareth\My Documents\"
Output: "C:\Users\Gareth\Documents\"

Comment: This works with symbolic links.  That should work on any function that takes a path.  Which ones don't?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: MapFileAndCheckSum() is the one that we have found has issues. It is clearly a legacy function because its internal implementation doesn't even support unicode.

Comment: @Hans do you want to post an answer with what you said? It's probably the most correct response I'm going to get to this question, so I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with symbolic links. That should work on any function that takes a path, MSDN documentation is here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I verified MapFileAndCheckSum(), it works fine.  Windows7, compiled with UNICODE in effect.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <imagehlp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "imagehlp.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD hdrsum, chksum;
    const wchar_t* path = L"c:\\documents and settings\\hpassant\\my documents\\test.exe";
    DWORD retval = MapFileAndCheckSum(path, &hdrsum, &chksum);
    assert(retval == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need? 
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents

Comment: I use the SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() function to retrieve the location of the correct folder for the current system. What I need to work out is how to migrate data created on Windows XP to Windows 7, where the return value of this function has changed.

Comment: Why don't you just replace string? function which gets your string as input and replace C:\Documents and Settings\Gareth\My Documents\ to C:\Users\Gareth\Documents\. I don't know exactly winapi function, but you need somthing like String.Replace(string, string) in c#

Comment: I'm not confident that this will work with all data that might need to be handled - for example, some users may have data in My Pictures or some other location that has changed. I could try to work out what all the possible folders that may have moved might be, but given that Windows already does this behind the scenes for some functions, I was hoping there would be an API I could just use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where exactly you're using this (and it's been a while since I've used Windows), but I remember being able to use the %HOMEPATH% variable to get the current user's Documents & Settings directory: \Documents and Settings{username}. I think that this works with the updated Windows 7 paths, too.

Comment: I use the SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() function to retrieve the location of the correct folder for the current system. What I need to work out how to do is to migrate data created on Windows XP to Windows 7, where the return value of this function has changed.